# What causes a nan error result?

Tags: objective-c, c

I have this chunk of code which runs through a loop. The lower case `x` var always prints correctly. The upper case `X` var sometimes **prints correctly**, sometimes prints `nan` or `junk`. Why?

**N.B. The data is always identical.**

[Link to FFT](http://pastebin.com/DwmZEPBt)

[Link to FFT example usage](http://pastebin.com/XGGPkPGM)

[Link to my other SO question which shows how this is being used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922289/problems-allocating-memory-in-c) **BOUNTY OF 200 points!**

```
double (*x)[2];
double (*X)[2];

x =  malloc(2 * 512 * sizeof(double));
X =  malloc(2 * 512 * sizeof(double)); 

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    (*x)[j] = // values inserted from method argument.; 
}

fft(512, x, X);

for (j = 0; j < 512; j++){
    if (i==512*20) {
        NSLog(@"PRE POST %f - %f",(*x)[j], (*X)[j]);
    }
}
    free(x);
    free(X);
```

Comment: This does not look like a C/Objective-C specific problem. Perhaps FFT is either not defined on the entire spectrum of values you are trying to calculate it on. Or it is defined but tangentially 0.0 or infinite.

Answer (score 2):

In floating point arithmetic, there are several operations that will result in a NaN error. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN) points out these operations as resulting in a NaN:

> - The divisions 0/0 and ±∞/±∞
> - The multiplications 0×±∞ and ±∞×0
> - The additions ∞ + (−∞), (−∞) + ∞ and equivalent subtractions

(These are called [indeterminate forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_forms).)

Check your code to see if you're performing any operations that can't have a numeric answer.

As for the 'junk' results, they may be the result of messed up memory allocation, but you haven't given much detail so I can't be sure.

Comment: I do believe both the `NaN` and the junk results are a memory issue, since the method is run on the same data every single time, yet produces different results. What do you think?

Comment: If it's exactly the same data each time with the same method, then I see few other options. Looking at your code, `double (*X)[2];` and `double (*x)[2];` combined with `malloc(2 * 512 * sizeof(double))` look strange to me. It would not create two arrays of 512 pointers; arrays (formed with `[]`) are unmodifiable. And when you call `(*x)[j]`, you're calling for example `(*x)[510]`, which makes no sense when you look at the declaration. I wouldn't use arrays in this case, in combination with dynamic memory, I think it's causing the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry if the explanation's a bit rough. I might post a full answer after I research this a little more.

Comment: I have posted links to the FFT code and usage example. If you get a chance to check it out, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages which I have worked in, "NaN" (not a number) is what you get when you divide a `0.0` by `0.0`. I don't know Objective-C, but it's likely the same.

As for what is causing `nan` to be stored in `X`... you'll have to show us the body of `fft` before anyone can answer that. You said you think it might be a memory/pointer bug, because it's not consistent. I just looked up how NaN is represented in the IEE 7754 floating point format (which your platform is likely using) -- basically, several of the high-order bits (which normally hold the exponent of a floating-point number) all have to be filled with 1s.

If you do have a memory corruption bug, which is causing junk to be stored into `X`, then if those particular bits happened to all be 1s, that would cause the number to print as "nan".

Again, please show the body of `fft`, so someone can try to help you further.

Comment: “"nan" (not a number) is what you get when you divide a double by 0.0” You're thinking of infinity. NaN is what you get when you divide 0 by 0, among other things.

Comment: I feel like this may be a memory issue. Especially since it sometimes works and sometimes produces junk. Or is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: @AlexD Uploading the fft now. One minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this - initialised the data using `(*x)[j] = j` and removed the `i==512*20` printing condition.  All values came back fine.  I also tried with random input data - still good.  What is the nature of your input data?

(I'll look at your other question as well)

edit: I should point out I filled 512 values of the x array - your loop above only fills 10, so much of the input array is uninitialised.